# How is the help feature for writing comments implemented on this site?

Tags: support, comments

Of the half dozen or so stackexchange sites I have personal experience with, this one, webmasters, is the only one I have seen where as soon as I start to write a comment, the Help cheatsheet is activated below the comment box.

Is this a feature that was consciously chosen?  Is it all in my imagination?

I like it, by the way.  It looks as though it was decided that the help cheatsheet should be visible by default, with the user having the option of hiding it by clicking on "hide help" -- rather than the opposite, which is what I've seen at other stackexchange sites, where the default is for the cheatsheet to start out hidden, but the user can activate it by clicking on "help".

My guess is that webmasters frequently need to post code in comments, and therefore it was decided to make the help box visible by default.  Is that right?

Does this behavior depend on the user's rep?

Comment: I think it must depend on reputation.  I have to click the help link to the right of the comment box to see the section.   I don't see it by default on any SE sites.  I think that is because I takes the +100 bonus for linking accounts.